# release CFString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, cfstring

I use this code to get the last name of ABPerson

```
CFStringRef lastNameRef = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)personRecordRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
NSString *friendLastName = (NSString*)lastNameRef;
CFRelease(lastNameRef);
```

it work fine when the value of last name is not equal to NULL 
but when the this value is NULL the application crash at the third line because I try to relese NULL

the question is witch is the best way to releasing the CFString in this case without causing the crash of the application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an if to check for NULL.

```
if (lastNameRef != NULL)
    CFRelease(lastNameRef);
```

Comment: You must *always* do this before calling `CFRetain()` or `CFRelease()`. It is part of those functions' contracts.

Answer (score 2):

CFRelease is old C style code. One should check for NULL before calling CFRelease as also set lastNameRef to NULL after calling CFRelease.

`if (lastNameRef != NULL)
{
    CFRelease(lastNameRef);
    lastNameRef = NULL;
}`

Answer (score 2):

`CFRelease` expects a non-NULL pointer. You could check for that with an `if` statement, but it is easier to simply release or autorelease `friendLastName` instead:

```
CFStringRef lastNameRef = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)personRecordRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
NSString *friendLastName = (NSString*)lastNameRef;
// use friendLastName
[friendLastName release];
```

or

```
CFStringRef lastNameRef = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)personRecordRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
NSString *friendLastName = (NSString*)lastNameRef;
[friendLastName autorelease];
// use friendLastName
```

As you don't seem to use `lastNameRef`, you could also inline that variable:

```
NSString *friendLastName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)personRecordRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
// use friendLastName
[friendLastName release];
```

or

```
NSString *friendLastName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)personRecordRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
[friendLastName autorelease];
// use friendLastName
```

Comment: The original question was for non-ARC, which can be inferred by the (NSString *) cast in it.

To do this with ARC, replace (NSString *) with (__bridge_transfer NSString *) and delete the release/autorelease lines.